# Unable to set Kendodropdownlist Width

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendodropdownlist as follows.

```
@ (Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name("AllocatePremiumBy")
    .DataTextField("AllocationMethodName")
    .DataValueField("AllocationMethodID")
    .BindTo(ViewBag.AllocateMethods as IEnumerable < KendoPOC.Models.AllocationMethod > )
    .OptionLabel(new {
    AllocationMethodName = "Please Select", AllocationMethodID = 0
}))
```

I am trying to set the width of this dropdownlist as follows.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var dropdown = $("#newPlanDropDown").data("kendoDropDownList");

    dropdown.list.width(400);
})
```

However i am not able to set the width,and i am getting error.dropdown value is either null or undefined.Where i am going wrong,Please help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set dropdown's width using HtmlAttributes. Try this code

```
@ (Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name("AllocatePremiumBy")
    .HtmlAttributes(new {style = "width:350px"})
```

Answer (score 0):

The kendoDropDownList does not have a property width for it's configuration. 
**[Kendo Docs](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/dropdownlist)**

What you can do, is styling the correct class. Since you hopefully do know where your dropdown lies, you can specify the selector so it doesn't apply to all dropdowns.

```
#newPlanDropDown .k-dropdown {
     width: 400px;
}
```